# Service-Based Database in VS2015 not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

So I've been trying to make this POS system and I simply cannot manage to get the Service-based Database to work it just throws me this error:

[image: This is the error]

Heres my running SQL related processes:

[image: Processes]

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have a SQL Service instance already running.  So, are you getting the error when trying to connect to it within your C# code?  If so, check the connection string and show us your SQL connection code.  Are you trying to connect from the same machine or another machine on the network?  Or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: @Don I started a clean solution and tried to add service-based db but the error persists